# How to sign transactions offline via geth for a specific chain?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, offline, networkid

Is there a way to sign a transaction to be accepted on a specific chain?

In other words, if I want to sign an offline transaction via geth, say 0.5 eth from external address A to external address B, is there a way to specify the desired chain to be Kovan/Mainnet/etc in the transaction?

I'm hoping to prevent a malicious actor from broadcasting the hash of the signed transaction on another chain (like mainnet, when the txn was meant for a testnet). E.g. replay attack

On geth, I've tried to sign a transaction offline through `eth.signTransaction( )`:

`var tx = eth.signTransaction({from:YOURADDRESS, to:TOADDRESS, gas:GAS, gasPrice:GASPRICE, nonce:19, value:500000000000000, networkId:1},YOURADDRESS)`

In place of the "networkId" parameter, I've tried the following combinations of parameters and arguments:

- `networkId:1`
- `networkId:42`
- `chainId:1`
- `chainId:42`

The `tx.raw` or hash of the signed transaction for each confirguration returns the **same** bytecode. I was even able to broadcast and submit a txn on kovan with a `chainId:1` argument.

Pls help. Thank you in advance!